# Sum NA values in r

Tags: r, sorting, na

I am using a dataframe that has multiple NA values so I was thinking about sorting the attributes based on their NA values.
I was trying to use a `for` loop and this is what I have so far:

```
> data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Nikita/Desktop/first1k.csv")
> for (i in 1:length(data) ) {
+ temp <- c(sum(is.na(data[i])))}
> temp
[1] 0
```

It is the first time I am using a for loop in r so I am sure it is just a silly syntax problem but I can't understand which one exactly.

Ultimately, I need a list that shows the name of the attribute and its NA count. This way I could sort the list and get the desired information. Here is some mock data to make it easier.

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(500, 600, 700, 1000),
                   B = c(500, 600, 700, NA),
                   C = c(NA, NA, 500, 700),
                   D = c(800, NA, 933, NA),
                   E = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Edit:
Thank you all for the help. All three solution worked for me. I do wonder though if there is a one line code that will sort those attributes before I export them into a file. like I mentioned before, I am quite new in `r` so I am not sure if it is possible.

Edit 2:
When I run the sort is gives me the next error:

```
temp <- sort(temp)
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do iterative code in R is to avoid explicit `for` loops. Use `apply` (and the company) instead. @jeremycg gave you the right R-ish answer. Regarding your code, you should make some editing to make it work.

```
temp <- c()
for (i in 1:length(data)){
    temp[names(data)[i]] <- sum(is.na(data[i]))
}
```

You had `temp` rewritten at each iteration. Moreover you didn't write the labels of your variables into `temp`. Hence the output you see is the number of `NA`s in the last column of your dataset.

**Regarding OP's edit**

```
temp <- sort(temp) # pass decreasing=T into arguments in case
                   # you want reversed order
```

Comment: `temp <- c()` is another option. I usually don't use lists when each element is a scalar.

Comment: @Frank Indeed, that would even produce a nicer output.

Comment: Thank you. I figured the temp was the issue but couldn't fix it. I edited the post with a quick question about sorting.

Comment: I tried to run it but it gives me an error. Edit 2.

Comment: @User that was due to `temp` being a `list`. I forgot to mention that you were supposed to initialize `temp` as a `vector`, i.e. `temp <- c()` in order to use `sort`.

Comment: Please don't promote growing objects in a loop. Pre-allocate to the final size: `temp <- integer(length(data))`

Comment: @Roland that is a valid point, though I wouldn't use a  loop in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick answer using `is.na` and `colSums`:

```
colSums(is.na(data))
```

returning:

```
 A B C D E 
 0 1 2 2 4
```

for your above data.

Thanks to @akrun for showing my surplus `apply`

Comment: Another option is `colSums(is.na(data))`

Comment: This works by applying the is.na function along every column (the 2), then summing each column, where a false is summed as 0, and a true as 1

Comment: Thanks guys, I've removed the surplus apply function - for posterity, I had: colSums(apply(data,2,is.na))

Comment: Thank you! Simple and does the job. I added an edit if you can help with the sorting process.

Comment: sure, try apply(data, 2, sort, na.last = TRUE)

Comment: I would actually leave the `apply` solution as an alternative as it has good educational value.

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows how to make the for loop work.

```
temp <- vector(length = ncol(data))

for (i in 1:length(data)) {
   temp[i] <- c(sum(is.na(data[, i])))
}

names(temp) <- colnames(data)

temp
# A B C D E 
# 0 1 2 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you. Pretty similar to Java actually. I edited the post regarding the sorting process so it would be great if you could look at it.

Comment: Since my answer produces a vector, you can just call `sort(temp)`. However, I don't intend for you to use the for loop as other users have mentioned. I was simply showing you how to fix yours in case you ever need to use a for loop for some reason.